# Looking for Exhaustive List of Firefox Hotkeys

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I'm looking for a definitive list of all Firefox 58 hotkeys / keyboard shortcuts. I am trying to use the mouse less in Firefox, and I want the hotkeys to guide the change in my browsing behavior while also memorizing the shortcuts. While researching, I found [this general Mozilla support website](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) as well as [this Firefox Developer Tools list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts). I have a sneaking suspicion that these websites just give the most commonly used shortcuts, but I want also the obscure (if I can get my hands on them).

I tried peeking at the source code on [Mozilla's Github](https://github.com/mozilla?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=firefox&type=&language=), but I really failed at that.

Could anyone tell me how to scrape all possible Firefox shortcuts? Or perhaps, where I might find a complete list? Or maybe even an alternate solution to my goals?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic

Comment: I don't think my question falls under "product, service, or learning material recommendations" because I ask for proof/disproof of my claim concerning all possible Firefox hotkeys. If someone provides a more in-depth reference than what I cited, then that would prove my claim false, answering my question. Even though the claim has to do with reference material, I am not explicitly asking for recommended references. It just so happens that providing additional research is a not unlikely outcome of the discussion, but then again, citing sources should be a part of any productive discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Execute `grep -rE 'commandkey|&\.key'` over the Firefox sources and you'll get a bunch of them. I don't know if this results in a complete list, but it appears all the common keyboard shortcuts match this regex.

For instance, here's a line for the about:addons keyboard shortcut:

```
browser/base/content/browser-sets.inc:    <key id="key_openAddons" key="&addons.commandkey;" command="Tools:Addons" modifiers="accel,shift"/>
```

`modifiers` lists keys such as Ctrl/Command (`accel`) and Shift. `command` gives a hint as to what the keyboard shortcut does, and the value of `key` is given in another file:

```
browser/locales/en-US/chrome/browser/browser.dtd:<!ENTITY addons.commandkey            "A">
```

Therefore, the complete key combination for the keyboard shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+A.